# Compare worksheets and insert new rows

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have two sheets with six columns of data, both in the same format, except that `Sheet 1` has historic data and `sheet 2` has newer data with some additional rows. Both sheets are sorted in order of the contents in the 2nd column followed by the 4th column.

I want to prepare a macro that compares both sheets and looks down the 2nd and 4th columns to identify the new rows in `Sheet 2` that are not in `Sheet 1` and color highlight these rows in `Sheet 2`. In addition, I would like the new rows from `sheet 2` to be inserted into Sheet 1 in the correct order.

For Example

[image]

The reason for doing all this as opposed to just copying the entire contents of `Sheet 2` into `Sheet 1` is because `sheet 1` has a number of formulas beyond the 6 columns which reference certain blocks of cells and it is require that these references be preserved. I currently have to manually insert each new row and given the amount of data being processed, this takes quite some time. I have tried adapting other macros that I found across the internet to perform this task but they don’t quite work.

Comment: couldn't you do this with a formula and conditional formatting?

Comment: where are we on this question ? If you received an answer please mark it

Answer (score 1):

## Step #1: identify rows that are in sheet2 and not in sheet1

Create a new column E in both sheets with this formula:

```
=B2&D2
```

(starting from row 2 and auto fill it to the entire column)

in sheet2 create column F with this formula

```
=ISERR(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!E2,Sheet1!E:E,1,FALSE))
```

Now column F would be `TRUE` only for rows that aren't in sheet1.

Next you'll need to add conditional formatting for `F=TRUE`

## Step #2: Copy the missing data

1. Filter rows from sheet2 with `F=TRUE`
2. Copy them to the end of sheet1
3. Sort sheet1

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the data (excluding the header) from Sheet2 underneath the data in Sheet1 and subsequently a) remove duplicates then b) sort on columns B and D, you should achieve the results you are looking for.

```
Sub collect_and_sort()
    With Sheets("sheet1")
        Sheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Copy _
          Destination:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1)
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2, 4), Header:=xlYes
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Key2:=.Columns(4), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

From the data on two sheets like this (shown on one sheet for space considerations),

[image: Collect and Sort before]

You will have this after the macro has run.

[image: Collect and Sort after]

I will admit I am unclear on whether the *3000/b* in Sheet1!B11:D11 was a typo or an actual duplicate record. The macro *does* reproduce your desired results.